# Can't make c:forEach and c:out works (I get a blank page)

Tags: java, jsp, foreach

I create the follow JSP page to display a list of itens from a database, but when I run the application in the container tomcat7, I get a blank page:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Lista de produtos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="display">
        <table border=2>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Vendor</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${item.model}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${item.vendor}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${item.price}"/></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This page is triggered by the following method doGet from my servlet:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String parametro = request.getParameter("p");
    List<equipment> lista = new ArrayList<equipment>();
    if(parametro.equals("*")) {
        try {
            lista = FindAllItens();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            lista = FindItens(parametro);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    request.getSession().setAttribute("list", lista);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Someone have an idea what may be missing for make the page works?

Comment: Don't you need to "reference" the library that imports the `c:` prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare the usage of the taglib at the top of the page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Always look at the generated source code to see what has really been generated. You'll find `<c:out>` in the HTML, which is a sign that the JSP engine doesn't recognize `<c:out>` as a tag, but as simple text.

That said, if you really get a completely blank page, then you're probably not even executing this JSP. You shoul at least see the page title and the table header.

Comment: Yes, I can see the page title and table header; I said blank page because no more data are displayed: only the empty table. I made the chage you suggest, and now receive a page with the error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application, what i guess is solved finding the right URL (i am presuming the url was changed).

Comment: The URL is correct. What you need to do is to add the JSTL jar(s) in your webapp. Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: I read the text, and include the JAR in the directory /WEB-INF/lib of my webapp, but still don't work (same error message is shown)

Comment: never mind, i have included only one of the two JARs. Now is working fine. Thank you for your help.